# MQTT certificates verification fails

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, ssl-certificate, python

I'm been desperately trying to get my MQTT clients to connect to my MQTT broker which is set up with a certificate from a CA (Letsencrypt).

To be able to get the CA certificate, I've used the letsencrypt python command (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/letsencrypt/0.4.1)

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -d www.myserver.com
```

This has given me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Mar  6 23:50 cert.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Mar  6 23:50 chain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   46 Mar  6 23:50 fullchain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 Mar  6 23:50 privkey.pem
```

These files I am also using for the SSL encryption on my website (apache2) which seems to work just fine as in my conf file:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

And when going on my webserver, I see the SSL icon, and it works.

Now, when I put these files inside my /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:

```
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/fullchain.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/cert.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/privkey.pem
```

And I was able to start the broker, v1.4.8 fine:

```
[ ok ] mosquitto is running.
```

and from the log:

```
1457462631: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Sun, 14 Feb 2016 15:06:55 +0000) starting
```

Yet, when I try to subscribe to the test topic, to, well, test, using this command from the client:

```
mosquitto_sub version 1.4.8 running on libmosquitto 1.4.8.
```

Running command:

```
root@titan:~# mosquitto_pub -h www.myserver.com -p 8883 -t test --cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myserver.com/fullchain.pem
```

It mentions in my command line:

```
Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).
```

A more curious look inside to mosquitto.log file reveals me:

```
1463562141: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1463562154: New connection from X.X.X.X on port 8889.
```

Which gives me surprising little information. A python script I use from a website gives me a little bit more information;

Python script:

```
import os, subprocess, socket, sys, time, struct import *
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

dir = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server.com/"

def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        exit(rc)
    else:
        mqttc.disconnect()

def on_disconnect(mqttc, obj, rc):
    obj = rc

run = -1
mqttc = mqtt.Client("08-ssl-connect-crt-auth", run)
mqttc.tls_set(dir + "fullchain.pem", dir + "cert.pem", dir + "privkey.pem")
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

mqttc.connect("www.server.com", 8889)
while run == -1:
    mqttc.loop()

exit(run)
```

And this returns me:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I'm at a loss here. This makes no sense to me! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This suggests that the hostname you are connecting with doesn't match the hostname in the certificate.

With `mosquitto_pub` try using the `--insecure` option.

Alternatively, you've not got the right chain of CA certificates and so the server cert can't be verified by the client.

Comment: After performing a command line: openssl x509 -noout -subject -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server.com/fullchain.pem, I recieved subject= /CN=www.server.com  - I can only assume that in that case the hostname does match the one in the certificate (also I use this for apache2, so it points correctly?) unless I am looking somewhere wrong?

Comment: Also, when I checked the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ for the CA I'm with, and the .crt file matches mine. So I don't think the chain is wrong? How can I debug this better? I feel like I'm not getting enough information to know what's wrong...

Comment: Using `mosquitto_pub --insecure ...` helped us figure out what was going on with our situation. We are using a Wildcard certificate, so the hostname doesn't match.. I'm not sure how to ensure we're talking to the correct server now, though.. ? Also, some clients (windows docker/moby) `mosquitto_pub` works (without --secure), while some clients don't work (raspian, fedora).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete this using Java. Also try to use MQTTBox app on MacBook to see if you are able to connect.

Check this MQTTBox Configuration:
[image: Check this MQTTBox Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a weak crypto algorithm is part of your Key/Certificate. E.g. debian has increased the requirements with updates to openssl-1.1.1 see https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1

To get a list of supported algorithms with `ECLEVEL=2` use following openssl command: `openssl ciphers -s -v 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=2'`

In most cases you have chosen a rsa key with <= 1024 bit or sha1 as has algorithm for the signature.
Run `openssl x509 -in yourcert.crt -noout -text` and check for `Public-Key:` and `Signature Algorithm:` attributes.

If you key is too small you need to recreate the complete set key+cert. If only the Signature Algorithm is too weak you can recreate the certificate only:
You can either create a new CSR from your existing key and information from your certificate:

`openssl x509 -x509toreq -in sha1.crt -signkey sha1.key -out sha256-new.csr -sha256`

or overwrite the algorithm while signing the existing CSR again:

`openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in sha1.csr -CA DummyCA-DonotTrust.pem  -CAkey DummyCA-DonotTrust.pem -CAcreateserial -out sha256.crt -sha256`

`-sha256` is the important part. Recent openssl version should use sha256 as default.